# Best scenario to avoid memory leaks on iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, pulse

I'm building an application that reads rss files something like Bing or Pulse, so I've built a class (UIViewController) that shows each individual entry in the feed and a class that contains that list of entries and another class that shows all the feeds at once, and I've not used any xib files so I've implemented a method in each class that gets called after each rotation to reset the frames of the views inside that class. But I'm facing a problem in the memory especially when calling that method when a rotation happens knowing that it just assigns a CGRect to each frame in the view.
So could you please help me to avoid this problem or suggest a different way to avoid it, and am I right about not using xib files or should I use them when ever I can and set the rotation thing inside them (using the auto resizing mask).

And if there is some complex free example like those applications, could any body point me to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no reason to avoid nib files when they are useful to you. They are often useful. There is no reason to use nib files when they are not useful to you. If you have complex layout, they are definitely very useful. Whether to use them or not, however, is a personal choice based on the particular application. As a beginner, I would recommend using them and getting comfortable with them, and particularly relying on the Xcode templates to set them up correctly.

Nib files aren't your issue, one way or another here. You're leaking memory, and you need to investigate why. First, run the static analyzer to make sure there are no obvious errors. Then run your app under Instruments (Leaks) and look for large leaks. Then run your app under Instruments (Allocations) and look for what's eating the most memory. That should point you to your error.

The most likely cause, without any insight into your code, is that you are misusing ivars. Make sure that you access your ivars through accessors (except in `init`, `dealloc` and in the accessors). Directly accessing your ivars is the #1 cause of memory problems in iOS.

Comment: I'm accessing any view or view controller inside any other viewController via the self keyword inside the init and the alloc, and I've made sure that every alloc has a corresponding release or autorelease, but my problem is if I'm having a scrollView for example that contains about 25 webviews right now I'm keeping a reference to all those webview inside a list and when rotating the device I'm resizing each one through its reference and this what I'm basically asking about does this causes any problems? and thank you for your well explained answer.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the comment on my post. I think you have explained it very well and that makes me delete my post. It was sort of confusing considering its someone new to programming. I too have just about 6 months of obj-c dev exp. Needless to say i upvote this for its sheer detail.

Comment: 25 web views is a lot, but it isn't a leak. Why do you believe you're leaking?

Comment: Hi again, Thank you for your great help. I've made sure that there is no leaks using the static analyzer and the Instruments tools, and my app takes about 8 M.B in its worst case, but when I tab the button that loads the webviews it crashes with "Data Formatters Temporarily Unavailable..." and when this happens the allocated memory is about 3 M.B so I guessed this might be another error or the initialization of the webviews needs some resources that the Instruments tool was unable to detect.

Comment: Could you please tell me if this crash is because of the webviews and if so why the Instruments tool was unable to detect. and thanks again.

Comment: Look in the console log. There's probably an exception printed there explaining why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Release the objects properly which has been allocated and defined globally. Do not release the object of your UIViewController when it is active. Most of the leakage problems occur by releasing the object of the UIViewController before it reaches out of scope.